# Android time to byte array

Tags: java, android, time, bluetooth, arrays

I am trying to get the current time and date in an Android application and transmit it via Bluetooth.  I have tried using both Time and Calendar to get the hour, minute, second, month, day, and year minus 2000.  I then tried to cast each value to a byte and placed them into a byte array.  However, when I try to send the values over Bluetooth they come out wrong on the other side.  The format that I'm shooting for is a header (0xFF) followed by hour, minute, second, month, day, year.

```
public class Bluetooth extends Activity{
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private String bt_address;//00:18:E4:OC:67:FF
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;
    private InputStream inStream = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth);

    Button connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn_Connect);

    try{
        /*code removed, reads bt_address from a file or creates a file if no file exists yet*/

    } catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.getStackTrace();
    }

    connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            try{
                /*code removed, saves bt_address to a file*/
            }

            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            /*code removed, prompts user to turn on Bluetooth if not already on*/

            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(bt_address);
            try {
                    btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            try {
                    btSocket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        btSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {}
                }
            try {
                    outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
             } catch (IOException e) {}

            try {
                    inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {}

                    Time time = new Time();
                    byte[] msgbuf = new byte[7];

                    msgbuf[0] = (byte)0xFF;
                    msgbuf[1] = (byte)time.hour;
                    msgbuf[2] = (byte)time.minute;
                    msgbuf[3] = (byte)time.second;
                    msgbuf[4] = (byte)(time.month + 1);
                    msgbuf[5] = (byte)time.monthDay;
                    msgbuf[6] = (byte)(time.year - 2000);

                    outStream.write(msgbuf);
           }
)};
```

This code is set up to connect to a device using its Bluetooth address and send it the time stamp when a button is clicked.  It will connect to the device and send a long string of numbers in the process, but I'm beginning to think that it disconnects before it sends the time stamp.

Comment: "come out wrong" is pretty vague - what do you get? Note that you should just be able to call `outStream.write(msgbuf)` if it's an `OutputStream`.

Comment: When I receive the data on the other end and display it as integers I get some gibberish that I believe is coming from the connect command on the app and the last 7 numbers are not time values. The others have been overwritten, but the last 5 are 21, 58, 52, 67, 225. These should be the minute, second, month, day, and year minus 2000. I also never saw the header when the values were scrolling passed. A second run has given me 233, 52, 67, 225 as the last 4 numbers. The last 3 being the same both times would lead me to believe that those are the values that it thinks are month, day, and year.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code which is receiving the values... Oh, and also it doesn't help that you're swallowing any exception being thrown. Don't do that.

Comment: The receiving code is running on an Arduino board.  It's just a simple loop that reads the serial line from the Bluetooth device and prints it as an integer on an OLED screen using a library function.  That end of things should not be the issue.  Once I get the data sending correctly it will use the values that I send it to start a clock and save a time stamp.  I believe there may be an issue with my Bluetooth setup code on the app.  I'll update the question.

Comment: "That end of things should not be the issue" is very often a precursor to "Oh, it turned out that was the issue." Start off by separating out the two problems: 1) Can you get the right time values; 2) Can you get data across the wire correctly.

Comment: I extensively tested the Arduino code using a Bluetooth terminal app from the app store.  I even had this app reading a character from a text box and sending it with no problem. It receives data correctly and reads it back correctly.  The loop that I'm testing the received data with literally can not be any more basic than it is.

Comment: So have you tested sending hard-coded bytes via the same Java code? As I say, separate the two issues...

Comment: Yes and at one time that was working, but now it's not.  As far as I can tell nothing was changed from when that worked.  I'm fairly certain that the socket is closing before it gets the outStream.write now for some reason.  It just sends that string of numbers on the connect and ignores anything that I try to send, time stamp or otherwise.  Thank you for sticking with this by the way.  I've been ripping my hair out because of it for the last three days and it's just one in a long line of other issues that I need to fix before Thursday.

Comment: Your code has a *lot* of ignoring IOException in there. Does your real code really keep going like that? I'd suggest removing *all* your catch blocks, and just declare that your method throws IOException. Close the connection in a finally block. That way you won't be masking errors in the same way.

Comment: The rest of the code catches things properly.  The catches in this section kind of got neglected.  I've discovered that restarting my phone causes my values read from a text box to start transmitting again.  The time stamp values still appear to either be wrong or missing though.

Comment: I believe that the problem is that the app is not using stop bits and the Arduino board is.  When I send 255, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 I get 255, 1, 2, 32, 80 on the Arduino board.  I don't know of a way to change that in either of the programs.

Answer (score 0):

You send just one byte. Method outStream.write(int) needs int as parameter (only 8 bytes are important). So you send correctly. Have you flush messages?

It is important how you receive this message? You should read [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) method and cast integer to byte.

Maybe better solution is send bytes as [outStream.write(msgbuf)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29) and read as [inputStream.read(receiveBuffer);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: He's sending one byte *at a time* but in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Android [Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) class has built-in functions to convert a Time object into two different standardized string formats: [format2445()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#format2445%28%29) and [format3339()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#format3339%28boolean%29).  They are already there for you, implement open standards, and somebody else has done the QA.

The strings are going to be slightly longer than the format you are working with, but at this size I doubt it will matter.  Likewise, they will be only slightly more difficult for you to decode on the receiving side.  Balancing that, since it's a human-readable string, it will be easier for you to debug.

I suggest you use one of these two string formats.

Comment: The receiving side has to interpret the time stamp that I send it as integer values to start a clock on an Arduino board.  I'm not looking for a human readable version.